# One <option> List For Several <select> Elements

Tags: html

Is it possible to define one dropdown list in html and use it for several forms on one page?

I have this dropdown form:

```
<select name="test1" id="test1">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

And I will have much more forms like this but with the same list. like:

```
<select name="test2" id="test2">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select name="test3" id="test3">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**My question:** Is it possible to use one dropdown list for all forms? So I didn't have to copy each one? (there will be more than 200 lines in dropdown list)

Comment: No. At least not with HTML as you asked. You should do this server side when you create the page or Javascript in the client.

Comment: Not for select field options. (An HTML5 datalist could be referenced by multiple input fields, but that creates a slightly different input control, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element)

Comment: Hi - dont make Sergi confuse... I think is a bad formulated question. as I understand he wants use the select in different forms (documents) and not copy it into the same document. @Sergi -> can you clearify?

Comment: Turnip understood my question perfectly. I meant to do all this with HTML not using PHP or JS

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your server accepts PHP (normaly does)...

write this script and save it as:  myoption.php

```
<?php
echo 
'<select name="test1" id="test1">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>';
?>
```

then make an php-include at the desired point of your script and save this as yourformname.php

```
<?php
    include ("myoption.php");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I knew how to do it with server side or JS but wondered if there was option using pure HTML :)

Comment: "*I assume your server accepts PHP (normaly does)...*" No, servers do _not_ "Normally accept PHP". They only "accept PHP" if they are set up to run PHP as the server-side language.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to define one dropdown list in html and use it for
>   several forms on one page?

Yes - and you can clone the dropdown list client-side with javascript.

See:

```js
var numberOfAdditionalSelects = 3;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfAdditionalSelects; i++) {
    var additionalSelect = select1.cloneNode(true);
    additionalSelect.id = 'select' + (i+2);
    additionalSelect.setAttribute('name','select' + (i+2));
    body.appendChild(additionalSelect);
}
```

```html
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pure JavaScript:

```js
var html = document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML;
var x = 1;
var y = 3;
while (y !== x++)
  document.getElementById('test' + x).innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<select name="test1" id="test1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select name="test2" id="test2"></select>
<select name="test3" id="test3"></select>
```

With jQuery:

```js
var html = $('#test1').html();
var x = 1;
var y = 3;
while (y !== x++)
  $('#test' + x).html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test1" id="test1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select name="test2" id="test2"></select>
<select name="test3" id="test3"></select>
```

With HTML5 `<link>`

```
 <link rel="import" href="filename.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mainly two options.

You can integrate the logic of your combobox into your server code, or you can integrate it on your client code.

As I don't know what are you using in server-side, I will base my answer in the client side.

On javascript, you can create a variable with the HTML that is common to every select.

Then, just create a function that adds the rest of the combobox code based on input parameters to the common variable and inject the whole code into the DOM.